# Problema de movimiento de archivos al compilar proyecto con TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Estoy desarrollando un proyecto con [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) y tengo un problema.
No es la primera vez que sufro por esto y es por ello que consideré preguntar aquí a ver si conseguía una respuesta satisfactoria.

**El Proyecto**
Estoy haciendo un componente de [React](https://react.dev/) para subir a [npm](https://npmjs.org). Es un modal de diálogos
para simplificarme el crear formularios. De manera que solo envíe los campos que necesito
y se genere todo el formulario, devolviéndome los datos una vez haya sido llenado.

**Problema**
Al ser un componente de [React](https://react.dev/) es muy ineficiente usar herramientas como [Vite⚡](https://vitejs.org) o [create-react-app](https://create-react-app.dev/), esto es más que absurdo dado que solo es un componente de [npm](https://npmjs.org). Por ello opto por utilizar [tsc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) como [transpilador](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpilador).
Estoy usando la [declaración de módulos](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces-and-modules.html#pitfalls-of-namespaces-and-modules) para importar archivos estáticos tales como
.svg, .png, .jpeg, etc. y al momento de desarrollar, todo va perfecto, pero una vez que [transpilo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpilador) mi app, en el directorio ***dist*** no se incluyen ninguno de esos archivos y solamente están allí los archivos de [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript) generados por [tsc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html).

Este problema lo suelo tener muy a menudo cuando creo componentes de [React](https://react.dev/) para subir a [npm](https://npmjs.org) o algún otro sitio y normalmente uso herramientas como [cpy](https://npmjs.com/package/cpy) para copiar los archivos.

**Ejemplo usando Cpy**

```sh
cpy src/**/*.svg dist
```

**Problema de usar herramientas como cpy**
Cuando son muchos archivos de diferentes extensiones se entenderá que la lineá del comando se hace demasiado larga, además considero que si ya se declararon los módulos en un archivo [d.ts](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/module-d-ts.html) es repetitivo el volver a especificar que esos archivos se deben de copiar cuando son importados.

**Preguntas**

1. ¿Hay alguna manera de decirle a [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) que incluya estos archivos?
2. ¿Si se declararon en el archivo [.d.ts](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/module-d-ts.html) porque no se agregan?
3. ¿Hay algún paquete de [npm](https://npmjs.org) que resuelva esto?
4. ¿Cómo lo logran herramientas como [Vite⚡](https://vitejs.org)?

**Propuesta**
Si no consigo una manera fiable de solucionar esto y veo que más personas tienen este problema construiré un paquete con [Golang](https://go.dev) o [Node.js](https://nodejs.org) que lo resuelva.

**Archivos**
*[main.tsx](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions)*

```
// Este es solo un ejemplo
import icon from './assets/icon.svg'
export const SomeComponent = ()=>{
    return <img src={icon} />
}
```

*[global.d.ts](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/module-d-ts.html)*

```
declare module '*.svg' {
  const src: string
  export default src
}
```

*[tsconfig.json](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html)*

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES2020",
        "module": "ESNext",
        "outDir": "dist",
        "declaration": true,
        "declarationDir": "dist/types",
        "esModuleInterop": true,

        /* Bundler mode */
        "moduleResolution": "Bundler",
        "jsx": "react-jsx",
        "sourceMap": true,
        /* Linting */
        "strict": true
    },
    "include": ["src/global.d.ts", "src/main.tsx"]
}
```

¡Espero sus comentarios y ayuda si es posible!
Saludos

Comment: Normalmente el copiado de archivos de este tipo no es algo de lo que se encargue typescript en si mismo. En frameworks normalmente hay un intermediario que hace el build y es el que se encarga de mover archivos estáticos. Deberías añadir esbuild o algún otro bundler / builder.

Comment: Hay alguna forma de pasarle mi global.d.ts a esbuild para que sepa comp resolver los archivos?

Comment: Con esbuild puedes hacer un script de carga de archivos personalizado, y en el script puedes hacer lo que quieras... eres tú quien lo implementa. Puedes abrir el fichero, leerlo, parsearlo como quieras y usar esa info para mover los estáticos, si. Te recomiendo leer la info porque muchas cosas están ya hechas. Tienes la posibilidad de indicarle que mueva archivos con ciertas terminaciones por ejemplo. Pasarle el global.d.ts así tal cual, pues no me suena, pero lo mismo con las terminaciones te vale. Y si no lo dicho, puedes pasarle una función que haga exactamente lo que quieres y ya está